# Why are WatchKit classes not recognised in new .swift file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos

I am trying to create a new swift file in Xcode to house a class that derives from WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable. E.g.

```
import WatchKit

struct Bing: WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable {
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Use of undeclared type 'WKInterfaceObjectRepresentable'

However, if I add it to one of the standard files (ContentView.swift) it picks it up correctly.

I thought it might be to do with the target membership but it is exactly the same for my new Bing.swift as it is for ContentView.swift (WatchKit Extension).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you import the framework? I don't see it in your code. ```import SwiftUI```

Comment: That was the problem thanks, I was importing WatchKit in my new file not SwiftUI.

Comment: In case, when you have a doubt you can go to the documentation (either on Xcode or web) the framework to import is usually stated there : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/wkinterfaceobjectrepresentable on the right

Comment: Thanks, just getting started with SwiftUI and misunderstood this particular class. I appreciate the tip!

Comment: No worry, their is always a lot of information to digest when we start with a topic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also import SwiftUI:

`import SwiftUI`